# how to pick a value in order from first to last from a list i provide inside a textbox C# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Hello everyone am working on a project for work and I just started using C# and selenium. I need to pick a value in this case a name from a list I provide inside a textbox for example `jack david john eren kevin` they dont need to be a specific number of names and I need them to be inserted into a `TextBox` from which the first name will be picked and sent to a webpages text field I have tried to use a `random` function but that did not work i need it to pick in order from first to last `Jack->SENDKEYS` and then after its done filling up a request it would go to the following `David->SENDKEYS` and same scenario but its really important to not just send the one after the other but after the completion of the whole webpage i was using a demo google form for this so i could figure out how to do this but i got stuck here this is my code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } //names
    private void TextBox_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
      
    }
    //size
    private void size_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //string sizes = size.Text;
    }
    //emails
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        string emails = question1.Text;
        string fnames = name.Text;
        string region = country.Text;
        string sizes = size.Text;

        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\webdrivers");

        ChromeDriver drv; Thread th;

        string url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeI8_vYyaJgM7SJM4Y9AWfLq-tglWZh6yt7bEXEOJr_L-hV1A/viewform";

    
        

        HashSet<string> names = new HashSet<string>();
        
        names.Add("name1", names.Add("name2"));
        foreach (string name in names) ;
       
            


        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        
        
        driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput")).SendKeys(emails);
      
        driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaInput")).SendKeys(fnames);
        
        driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("quantumWizTextinputSimpleinputInput")).SendKeys(region);
       
        driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("quantumWizTextinputSimpleinputInput")).SendKeys(sizes);
       
    }

   
}
```

` and it need to be connected to the textbox so that i could just place the textbox name into send keys command thank you!

Comment: This question is also rambling. You need to be much more concise. Punctuation would help too.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're after here, but would this help you get started?

```
var names = new HashSet<string>()
{
    "jack",
    "david",
    "john",
    "erin",
    "kevin"
};

var namesElement = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaInput"));

foreach (string name in names)
{
    namesElement.SendKeys(name); 
}
```

Comment: Am trying to input the names i provided inside a textbox from which the code will take 1 at a time  and how does that last line of code work?   namesElement.SendKeys(name); I have something like this as well but i keep getting errors any way you could help me?